# How to copy text with font style in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a copy button that gonna copy text with font style. I tried but it is coping only text.

Like many website have copy button that copy text with font style. (ex- ) you can copy and paste this anywhere.

Demo-search keyword "fancy text generator" and i also mentioning some websites links
Demo 1- https://www.fancytextpro.com/FancyTextGenerator/Unique
Demo 2- https://coolsymbol.com/cool-fancy-text-generator.html

In the above mentioning websites demo they are replacing the character with their fancy characters.

HTML

```
<div class="canvas" id="canvasid">welcome</div>
<button onclick="copy">Copy</button>
```

I made a simple copy button and its coping text only, need a function that fetch font style from Hello and let user allow to copy text with font style, so user can paste it on other social media like instagram, whatsapp.

Comment: Those websites don't copy text with a certain font. They convert them to different (unicode) characters.

Comment: **Danger**:  is not a font style. They are [symbols used in mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols) which look like letters. Using them as words will break screen readers. Introducing this kind of accessibility barrier should be avoided for moral, legal, and practical (you want people to be able to read your content!) reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I think the method used by [FancyText Pro](https://www.fancytextpro.com/FancyTextGenerator/Unique) to copy fancy text doesn't necessarily copy the font style generated from the input text, but it uses [mathematical symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols) to replace each character in the input text as stated by [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin). It is implemented by making a POST request on the FancyText Pro API (*The `text` parameter in the URL below contains an example of input text*):

```
[POST] https://www.fancytextpro.com/generate?text=stackoverflow&_csrf=&pages%5B%5D=Unique&pages%5B%5D=CoolText&pages%5B%5D=Elegant
```

The request generates a JSON response like this:

```json
{
     "neonCharMap": "ᔕTᗩᑕKOᐯEᖇᖴᒪOᗯ",
     "boldCharMap": "gulung",
     "italicCharMap": "ana",
     "NinjaText": "ꞩⱦⱥȼҟꝋꝟēɍӻłꝋⱳ",
     "Ladyleo": "❀ ᔕTᗩᑕKOᐯEᖇᖴᒪOᗯ ❀",
     "boldItalicCharMap": "",
     "monospaceCharMap": "",
     "FreeFireText": "★彡( ₴₮₳₵₭ØVɆⱤ₣ⱠØ₩ )彡★",
     "BoldFloara": "ꗥ～ꗥ gulung ꗥ～ꗥ",
     "upperAnglesCharMap": "ƧƬΛᄃKӨVΣЯFᄂӨЩ",
     "greekCharMap": "ѕтα¢кσνєяƒℓσω",
     "DarkAngelText": "◤✞  ✞◥",
     "SunnyDay": "❂ ⳜƬƇƘⰙƲƸⱤƑȴⰙⱲ ❂",
     "invertedSquaresCharMap": "",
     "doubleStruckCharMap": "",
     "CaravanText": "ֆȶǟƈӄօʋɛʀʄʟօա ",
     "Dessert": "ⲯ﹍︿﹍︿﹍  ﹍ⲯ﹍ⲯ﹍︿﹍☼",
     "oldEnglishCharMap": "",
     "taiVietCharMap": "ᦓꪻꪖᥴᛕꪮꪜꫀ᥅ᠻꪶꪮ᭙",
     "oldEnglishCharBoldMap": "",
     "FooText": "ᕚ( รՇคςк๏שєгŦɭ๏ฬ )ᕘ",
     "oldItalicText": "ꝊᕓꝊᏔ",
     "cursive Letters": "",
     "cursiveLettersBold": "",
     "eyeOfHorusText": "  ",
     "BoldJavaneseText": "꧁༺  ༻꧂",
     "wideTextCharMap": "ｓｔａｃｋｏｖｅｒｆｌｏｗ",
     "subscriptCharMap": "ₐⲕₒᵥₑᵣԼₒｗ",
     "RainbowText": "gulung™",
     "GunText": "▄︻デֆȶǟƈӄօʋɛʀʄʟօա══━一",
     "superscriptCharMap": "ˢᵗᵃᶜᵏᵒᵛᵉʳᶠˡᵒʷ",
     "USAFlagText": " ʂƚαƈƙσʋҽɾϝʅσɯ ",
     "ak47GunText": "─╤╦︻ ⳜƬƇƘⰙƲƸⱤƑȴⰙⱲ ︻╦╤─",
     "MagicalText": "☆꧁✬◦°˚°◦. ֆȶǟƈӄօʋɛʀʄʟօա .◦°˚°◦✬꧂☆",
     "Blocky": " ▂▄▅▆▇█ ƧƬΛᄃKӨVΣЯFᄂӨЩ █▇▆▅▄▂",
     "JavaneseRerengganText": "꧁༺stackoverflow ༻꧂",
     "fadedBlock": "██▓▒░⡷⠂⠐⢾░▒▓██",
     "bracketCharMap": "",
     "gunFireText": "一═デ︻ ѕтα¢кσνєяƒℓσω ︻デ═一",
     "CupofTea": "ꓚ⌊⌋  ⌊⌋ꓛ",
     "HeartBeat": "♥ﮩ٨ـﮩﮩ٨ـﮩﮩ ѕтα¢кσνєяƒℓσω ﮩﮩـ٨ﮩﮩـ٨ﮩ♥",
     "Vaccinate": "╏╠══[  ]      ",
     "BoldQuoted": "❝gulung❞",
     "checksText": "▞▞▞▞▞▖▝▞▞▞▞▞"
}
```

Therefore, we can create a simple website that can apply the fancy text generator concept like this:

```js
let copyText = (element) => {
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  const range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(element);
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
  document.execCommand('copy');
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  alert("Text Copied: " + element.innerText);
}

let input = document.getElementById('input');
let divs = [...document.querySelectorAll('div[data-fancy-font]')];
input.onkeyup = () => {
  $.ajax({
    url: `https://www.fancytextpro.com/generate?text=${input.value}&_csrf=&pages%5B%5D=Unique&pages%5B%5D=CoolText&pages%5B%5D=Elegant`,
    type: 'POST',
    success: (response) => {
      divs.forEach((elm) => {
        let targetText = elm.children[1];
        let buttonCopy = elm.children[2];
        // update fancy font with response data
        targetText.innerText = response[elm.dataset.fancyFont];
        // copy fancy font
        buttonCopy.onclick = () => {
          copyText(targetText);
        }
      });
    },
    error: (err) => {
      divs.forEach((elm)=>{
        let targetText = elm.children[1];
        // update fancy font with empty string
        targetText.innerText = '';
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.canvas {
  width: 100%;
}

.canvas > div {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.canvas > div:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.canvas input:focus {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}

span.title {
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  transform: translate(0,-10px);
}

span.fancy {
  margin: 10px;
}

button {
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
}

button:active {
  transform: scale(0.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Your Fancy Text Generator</h3>
<div>
  <label for="input">Input Text :</label>
  <input id="input" type="text" />
</div>
<hr />
<div class="canvas" id="canvasid">
  <div data-fancy-font="oldEnglishCharBoldMap">
    <span class="title">Bold Calligraphy Text</span>
    <span class="fancy"></span>
    <button>Copy</button>
  </div>
  <div data-fancy-font="greekCharMap">
    <span class="title">Greek Text</span>
    <span class="fancy"></span>
    <button>Copy</button>
  </div>
  <div data-fancy-font="boldItalicCharMap">
    <span class="title">Bold + Italic Text</span>
    <span class="fancy"></span>
    <button>Copy</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

To be able to change the font to use another fancy text, you can change it to the `data-fancy-font` attribute according to the key you want contained in the JSON response.